Basement utility room has insulation in the joists - can I remove?
We have a utility room with gas furnace in the basement, in the winter, the utility room is about 75F, nice and warm.  The previous owner placed fiberglass batt and also some vapor barrier in each joist bay which covers approx 2/3 of the length of each joist bay.
In my opinion, it would seem to make more sense to remove the insulation and let the heat rise and help warm the floor in the above living room.  I'd also get some storage space in those bays.
Should I remove this insulation and vapor barrier?



What would you store in the joist bays and how?   You get a few small shelves at two ends of the room where you can put small things that are hard to reach.    Maybe some spare pipes, if you are a spare-pipe-owning sort.  But with bracing, wiring and plumbing it's usually hard to find useful space up there.

anything long-ish.  48" level, 48" LED bulbs, etc.

If the space above this mechanical room in insulated and conditioned, then it should be completely safe to remove.
I suspect the reason it was put there was for noise dampening, rather than heat insulation.

My thoughts exactly. If you want to reclaim the heat lost to the room, insulate the duct.
